# LEFT JOIN with case condition under it

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, left-join, case

I have a stored procedure which takes `@Table1.ColumnName` (name of the column) as input parameter. This is the query inside the stored procedure:

```
select data
from Table1               
    case @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column1'  
       THEN LEFT JOIN Table2  (on Table1.column1 = Table2.column1)

   case @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column2' 
       THEN LEFT JOIN Table2 
             (on Table1.column2 = Table2.column1)
```

I need to make a left join in the stored procedure by checking the input parameter `@Table1.ColumnName`. I need to alter the `ON` condition in the join.

I am not sure with the syntax. Could anyone help me how to write a left join with case condition.

Comment: I doubt that it will work this way. Why not generating a three procedures: two for each variant of the join and a third that get the column name as input and decides which of the implementation to use?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense as posted. Is @Table1 a table variable? Meaning you are trying to do a different join on each row in your table variable or something? You need to provide us a lot more information so we can help you find a solution.

Comment: any reason you can't just do two left joins?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do two left joins since the @table1.column1 variable won't match both, you know you'll only get results in one of them.  and you can always coalesce the results so you get the non-empty value from t2, t3 (col1 example below)

```
SELECT t1.*, coalesce(t1.column1, t2.column1) as Col1
FROM  Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
  on T1.column1 = t2.column1 
 and @table1.column1 = 'Table1.column1'
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 
  on T1.column2 = t3.column1 
 and @table1.column2 = 'Table1.column2'
```

Otherwise I believe you'd have to use dynamic SQL to accomplish what you're after.

Or I suppose you could union a blank result with a result...

```
SELECT data
FROM Table1               
LEFT JOIN table2 
  (on Table1.column1 = Table2.column1)
WHERE @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column1'  

UNION ALL

SELECT data
FROM Table1               
LEFT JOIN Table2 
  (on Table1.column2 = Table2.column1)
WHERE @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column2'
```

Comment: I like the second one better; I think it would go well with `option (recompile)` +1

Comment: Yeah I did too from a maintenance/readability standpoint  it may even be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic sql for this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
  select data
  from Table1
    left join Table2 
      on Table2.column1 = ';
if @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column1'
begin;
  set @sql = @sql + 'Table1.column1';
end;
if @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column2'
begin;
  set @sql = @sql + 'Table1.column2';
end;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this.

```
SELECT data
FROM Table1               
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON
  @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column1'  
  AND Table1.column1 = Table2.column1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON
  @Table1.ColumnName = 'Table1.column2' 
  AND Table1.column2 = Table2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying this code, based on the parameter `@ColName`, you will use different join condition

```
declare @ColName int = 'FieldNameHere'
select *
from Table1
    left join Table2
        on (Table1.column1 = Table2.column1 and @ColName = 'FieldNameHere')
            or (Table1.column2 = Table2.column2 and @ColName <> 'FieldNameHere')
```